# Creating a Snapchat bot in python

Tags: python

I am new in python programming and  I was trying to create a Snapchat bot
Can you help me create a request based Snapchat bot.
I will be using this for marketing with my existing clients to help schedule posts. It will also be an auto responder to act as Thank you or Welcome messages.

If you got any ideas you can share your thoughts, thank you

Basically I need a python script to handle message scheduling and auto response

Answer (score 0):

Snapchat now supports the web or browser. So you can take a look at the tutorials of `pyautogui` module in python. you can manipulate the keyboard and mouse events and respond to the messages with prewritten messages of yours. Your task can be done easily.